# Using async_hooks to access store in different module

Tags: node.js, express

Consider the following use of AsyncLocalStorage from async_hooks

**storage.js**

```
import { AsyncLocalStorage } from 'async_hooks'
export const storage = new AsyncLocalStorage()
```

**express.js**

```
import { storage } from './utils/storage'

App.use((req, res, next) => {
    const store = new Map();

    storage.run(store, () => {
       store.set("userName", "Bob");
       next();
    });
})
```

**module.js**

```
  import { storage } from './utils/storage'

  const store: any = storage.getStore(); // undefined

  storage.run(store, () => {
     const userName = store.get("userName")
  });
```

The issue I am having in this approach is that in module.js, storage.getStore() returns undefined and error is thrown

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

What is the proper way to share and access AsyncLocalStorage between different modules?

Comment: Where is the code in your `module.js` being executed? Is it being executed in a middleware or at the top level(i.e outside the express middleware)?

Comment: @Tunmee it can be executed in the middleware and outside of middleware as well

Comment: There is this comment about `storage.getStore()` from the official NodeJS doc; “_If called outside of an asynchronous context initialized by calling asyncLocalStorage.run() or asyncLocalStorage.enterWith(), it returns undefined_". The store was configured inside an async express middleware so trying to access the store outside the express middleware chain won't work. More details about `getStore` here https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#asynclocalstoragegetstore

Comment: @Tunmee Yes, I read it too, but there must be a way to access storage.getStore() is async way in in multiple modules, without it the whole premise of asyncLocalStorage seems to be important functionality.

Answer (score -2):

change your `module.js`

```js
  import { storage } from './utils/storage'

  const store: any = storage.getStore(); // undefined

  const someFunction = () => {
     const userName = store.get("userName")
  });
```

all get/set must in one run context, through them in another module.